# Look forwarding

Tags: word-usage

I have recently come across with the expression  "We look forwarding to ...ing". Are you familiar with forwarding instead of forward(s)? It sounds a little weird to me, since grammatically, forward is actually a preposition, not a verb! What do you think about this pattern? Does this structure sound correct to you? Do you know whether it's commonly used anywhere around? Thank you so much.

Comment: "We look forward to doing X" would be idiomatic US English.  "We look forwarding to ... " does not make any sense in any context I can think of.

Comment: You might *just* be able to get away with using 'forwarding' as a 'reference' instead of a 'use' if you had "We look *forwarding to subscribers* in the eye and decide instead on *caching*." I doubt that's what you're asking about, though. :)

Comment: "We look forwarding…" will always be wrong but whether it's a simple typing mistake or a serious problem of meaning or understanding is impossible to tell; the more so because you didn't bother to post the whole phrase…
"We look forward to (anything)…” even "We look forward to forwarding…” would work but those are different Questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the product of a typo, where the author's mind got a little to ahead of itself, and was thinking about the -ing ending of the intended verb, but inserted -ing to soon, because forward- is also a verb.  It might also be the product of erroneous computer editing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct English usage at all. One looks forward to ... meeting, dancing, flirting, talking, debating, etc.

**for·ward**

'fôrwərd - *verb*

gerund or present participle: **forwarding**

1. send (a letter or email) on to a further destination.
   "a forwarding address"
   synonyms:   send on, mail on, redirect, re-address, pass on
   "my mother forwarded me your email"
2. help to advance (something); promote.
   "the scientists are forwarding the development of biotechnology"

Comment: Can you add attribution and block quote format for that definition

Answer (score 0):

1. Forward is a noun, adjective, adverb and a **verb**.
2. Since "look forward" is a phrasal verb, the correct present continuous form is "looking forward" ,not "look forwarding". So the sentence you mentioned is grammatically wrong.
3. "I look forward" is more formal than "I'm looking forward" and mostly used in formal letters.

Good luck.